# Creating a select box with a search option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

I am trying to replicate  what you can see here in this image. [image]

I want to be able to either type in the text field above the box or just click on the option directly.

What would be the best way to go about that? Is there anything bootstrap related that exists already?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 123):

This simple code worked for me

```html
<input list="brow">
<datalist id="brow">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Incase you need to use only select tag use Selectize Js. It has all options we require .Please Try It [Demo using Selectize Js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57809086/10445069)

Comment: This allows the user to type in anything, not just the options provided. Also requires double click to open the dropdown list.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs - Yes , In that case , I suggest SelectJs, I am using it in my appplications & its great.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs - To be fair, if it *didn't* allow you to type in anything, it'd become a game of "guess the next correct letter that matches something in the list".

In that scenario, I don't believe the user would understand why the keys they're typing do not display in the input. It would actually seem very broken.

Comment: Is this feature HTML 5? because u didnt need Jquery

Comment: is there a way to not show the value, but just text in the dropdown?

Answer (score 84):

Selectize Js has all options we require .Please Try It

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').selectize({
          sortField: 'text'
      });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to upon selecting the right option there results can be posted

Comment: Seems cool, but can anyone explain why I see <input> when I inspect the field in the code runner? I don't see <input> in the sample code above, only select and option. I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Hello I have on click event set to my select field when I use your code + on click event only first option is being shown rest all being hidden, any workaround to have onlick event + search function?

<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Shanghai</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Germany</option>
    <option value="https://741.studio/nnroad/vietnam/">Taiwan</option>
</select> is my code

Answer (score 29):

Select2 http://select2.github.io may be even better and more active than Chosen.

See this comparison:
http://sitepoint.com/jquery-select-box-components-chosen-vs-select2

I went for Select2 (a few months ago) because Chosen had an issue when using Chinese characters via an IME http://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2663 It works great.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Not only it supports all languages, but also the container is not relatively positioned, which means it's compatible with any theme. I tried Chosen and because of a stupid `position:relative` parent it failed to work.

Answer (score 22):

You can use select2 . it is the best js for this job.
https://select2.org/dropdown

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
//change selectboxes to selectize mode to be searchable
   $("select").select2();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <select id="select_page" style="width:200px;" class="operator"> 
         <option value="">Select a Page...</option>
         <option value="alpha">alpha</option> 
         <option value="beta">beta</option>
         <option value="theta">theta</option>
         <option value="omega">omega</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21):

Full option searchable select box

This also supports Control buttons keyboards such as `ArrowDown` `ArrowUp` and `Enter` keys

```js
function filterFunction(that, event) {
    let container, input, filter, li, input_val;
    container = $(that).closest(".searchable");
    input_val = container.find("input").val().toUpperCase();

    if (["ArrowDown", "ArrowUp", "Enter"].indexOf(event.key) != -1) {
        keyControl(event, container)
    } else {
        li = container.find("ul li");
        li.each(function (i, obj) {
            if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(input_val) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

        container.find("ul li").removeClass("selected");
        setTimeout(function () {
            container.find("ul li:visible").first().addClass("selected");
        }, 100)
    }
}

function keyControl(e, container) {
    if (e.key == "ArrowDown") {

        if (container.find("ul li").hasClass("selected")) {
            if (container.find("ul li:visible").index(container.find("ul li.selected")) + 1 < container.find("ul li:visible").length) {
                container.find("ul li.selected").removeClass("selected").nextAll().not('[style*="display: none"]').first().addClass("selected");
            }

        } else {
            container.find("ul li:first-child").addClass("selected");
        }

    } else if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {

        if (container.find("ul li:visible").index(container.find("ul li.selected")) > 0) {
            container.find("ul li.selected").removeClass("selected").prevAll().not('[style*="display: none"]').first().addClass("selected");
        }
    } else if (e.key == "Enter") {
        container.find("input").val(container.find("ul li.selected").text()).blur();
        onSelect(container.find("ul li.selected").text())
    }

    container.find("ul li.selected")[0].scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
    });
}

function onSelect(val) {
    alert(val)
}

$(".searchable input").focus(function () {
    $(this).closest(".searchable").find("ul").show();
    $(this).closest(".searchable").find("ul li").show();
});
$(".searchable input").blur(function () {
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(that).closest(".searchable").find("ul").hide();
    }, 300);
});

$(document).on('click', '.searchable ul li', function () {
    $(this).closest(".searchable").find("input").val($(this).text()).blur();
    onSelect($(this).text())
});

$(".searchable ul li").hover(function () {
    $(this).closest(".searchable").find("ul li.selected").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
div.searchable {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.searchable input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 4 5'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23343a40' d='M2 0L0 2h4zm0 5L0 3h4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat right .75rem center/8px 10px;
}

.searchable ul {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #add8e6;
    border-top: none;
    max-height: 180px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.searchable ul li {
    padding: 7px 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #6e6e6e;
}

.searchable ul li.selected {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchable">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search countries" onkeyup="filterFunction(this,event)">
    <ul>
        <li>Algeria</li>
        <li>Bulgaria</li>
        <li>Canada</li>
        <li>Egypt</li>
        <li>Fiji</li>
        <li>India</li>
        <li>Japan</li>
        <li>Iran (Islamic Republic of)</li>
        <li>Lao People's Democratic Republic</li>
        <li>Micronesia (Federated States of)</li>
        <li>Nicaragua</li>
        <li>Senegal</li>
        <li>Tajikistan</li>
        <li>Yemen</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance for a Vanilla JavaScript solution for the code above?

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this without JavaScript using pure HTML Datalist element:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

References:

- [Can I use? - Datalist element detailed browser support](https://caniuse.com/datalist)
- [MDN - : The HTML Data List element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)
- [w3schools - HTML  Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp)

Answer (score 6):

This will work for most of us.
The answer given by ***Hemanth Palle*** is the easiest way to do it, It worked for me and the JS code wasn't necessary.
The only problem that I've found is that according to W3Schools, [The datalist tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input list="browsers">
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As of Safari 12.1, released 2019-03-25, now supports the `datalist` tag.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_12

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reach your goal with only vanilla js, then I strongly recommend to use [Tom Select library](https://tom-select.js.org/) which is forked from Selectize.js and then decoupled from jQuery.

```js
    new TomSelect("#select-state",{
        create: false,
        sortField: {
            field: "text",
            direction: "asc"
        }
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/css/tom-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tom-select@2.0.0-rc.4/dist/js/tom-select.complete.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
//change selectboxes to selectize mode to be searchable
   $("select").select2();
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <select id="select_page" style="width:200px;" class="operator"> 
         <option value="">Select a Page...</option>
         <option value="alpha">alpha</option> 
         <option value="beta">beta</option>
         <option value="theta">theta</option>
         <option value="omega">omega</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

This was good solution but, only problem is, its inefficient for large data

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31413214)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy open source library I made earlier that uses jQuery:
https://bitbucket.org/warwick/searchablelist/src/master/
And here is a working copy on my VPS: http://developersfound.com/SearchableList/
The library is highly customisable with overridable behavours and can have seperate designs on the same web page
Hope this helps

Comment: I found a link on the W3C web site:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reach your goal with a few updates in your code just do the following

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <!-- Be sure to put the links in the right position to avoid dependency issue.-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').selectize({
            sortField: 'text'
        });
    });

  // to clear the selected value.
   $('form').find('.selectized').each(function(index, element) { element.selectize && element.selectize.clear() })

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still finding this, you'll also want to consider Select2, which does all this easily. https://select2.org/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without any plugins. Only html and some jquery.
You can save following code sample as a html file and test it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $("#dropdown-values").addClass("show");
}

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if( e.target.id != 'myInput') {
    $("#dropdown-values").removeClass("show");
  }
});

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, a, i;
  filter = $("#myInput").val().toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function setValueOfInput(e) {
    $("#myInput").val(e.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  overflow: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block !important;}

.dropdown-values{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Dropdown with search</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" onclick="myFunction()">
    <div id="dropdown-values" class="dropdown-values">
        <a onclick="setValueOfInput(this)">option 1</a>
        <a onclick="setValueOfInput(this)">option 2</a>
        <a onclick="setValueOfInput(this)">option 3</a>
        <a onclick="setValueOfInput(this)">option 4</a>
        <a onclick="setValueOfInput(this)">option 5</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did my own version for bootstrap 4. If you want to use it u can check.
https://github.com/AmagiTech/amagibootstrapsearchmodalforselect

```js
amagiDropdown(
    {
        elementId: 'commonWords',
        searchButtonInnerHtml: 'Search',
        closeButtonInnerHtml: 'Close',
        title: 'Search and Choose',
        bodyMessage: 'Please firstly search with textbox below later double click the option you choosed.'
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="commonWords">Favorite Word</label>
                <select id="commonWords">
                    <option value="1">claim – I claim to be a fast reader, but actually I am average.</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>be – Will you be my friend?</option>
                    <option value="3">and – You and I will always be friends.</option>
                </select>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/AmagiTech/amagibootstrapsearchmodalforselect/9c7fdf8903b3529ba54b2db46d8f15989abd1bd1/amagidropdown.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -7):

This will done by using jquery. Here is the code

```
<select class="chosen" style="width:500px;">
<option>Html</option>
<option>Css</option>
<option>Css3</option>
<option>Php</option>
<option>MySql</option>
<option>Javascript</option>
<option>Jquery</option>
<option>Html5</option>
<option>Wordpress</option>
<option>Joomla</option>
<option>Druple</option>
<option>Json</option>
<option>Angular Js</option>
</select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".chosen").chosen();
</script>
```

Comment: Not really by jQuery, mostly by extension named chosen.js

Comment: This uses select instead of input datalist, so it loses the search functionality

Comment: @JamesBond im not sure if you checked the example link .. but this provides the search and select functionality. :) 
BTW i was in search something like this. got multiple choices now to select. THANKS