# Searchable select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

Is there anyway to make select option as selectable/auto complete/searchable? unfortunately i cannot change the form. so i cannot change the select option into text field. but i be able to access the css and javascript..

Below is the select option.

```
<select name="siteID" id="siteID" class="abcd" style="width:100%" /> 
            <option value='0' selected='true'> Not associated to any Circuit ID </option>
            <option value='2101' > 1007345136 </option> 
            <option value='2102' > 1007921321 </option> 
            <option value='2103' > 1007987235 </option> 
            <option value='2407' > 132 </option> 
            <option value='2408' > 141 </option> 
            <option value='2409' > 142 </option> 
            <option value='2410' > 145 </option> 
            <option value='2701' > 225 </option> 
            <option value='2702' > 248 </option> 
            <option value='2703' > 251 </option> 
            <option value='2704' > 254 </option> 
            <option value='2705' > 264 </option> 
            <option value='1804' > 27 </option> 
            <option value='2706' > 274 </option> 
            <option value='2707' > 310 </option> 
            <option value='2708' > 311 </option> 
            <option value='3001' > 333 </option> 
            <option value='2401' > 38 </option> 
            <option value='2402' > 64 </option> 
            <option value='2403' > 68 </option> 
            <option value='2404' > 69 </option> 
            <option value='2405' > 76 </option> 
            <option value='2406' > 81 </option> 
            <option value='2411' > abc123post </option> 
            <option value='3301' > circuit id 50 </option> 
            <option value='2105' > fadhil </option> 
            <option value='2104' > faisal </option> 
            <option value='3002' > IPEN - SITE TEST </option> 
            <option value='3601' > Manual Circuit ID </option> 
            <option value='3302' > new circuit id fadhil </option> 
            <option value='1809' > try iframe </option> 
        </select>
```

is there any javascript/jquery and css that can transform it as serchable.

Comment: Hi @user2748728, could you consider accepting one of the given answers, or giving feedback if none of them was helpful?

Comment: I updated my answer with a method for including external scripts with Javascript.

Comment: You can use this "Full option searchable select box": https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590636/6569224

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may consider using a jQuery plugin called [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). You **cannot** self-close a `<select>` tag! You can just use it this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $("select").select2();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select name="siteID" id="siteID" class="abcd" style="width:100%">
  <option value='0' selected='true'> Not associated to any Circuit ID </option>
  <option value='2101' > 1007345136 </option> 
  <option value='2102' > 1007921321 </option> 
  <option value='2103' > 1007987235 </option> 
  <option value='2407' > 132 </option> 
  <option value='2408' > 141 </option> 
  <option value='2409' > 142 </option> 
  <option value='2410' > 145 </option> 
  <option value='2701' > 225 </option> 
  <option value='2702' > 248 </option> 
  <option value='2703' > 251 </option> 
  <option value='2704' > 254 </option> 
  <option value='2705' > 264 </option> 
  <option value='1804' > 27 </option> 
  <option value='2706' > 274 </option> 
  <option value='2707' > 310 </option> 
  <option value='2708' > 311 </option> 
  <option value='3001' > 333 </option> 
  <option value='2401' > 38 </option> 
  <option value='2402' > 64 </option> 
  <option value='2403' > 68 </option> 
  <option value='2404' > 69 </option> 
  <option value='2405' > 76 </option> 
  <option value='2406' > 81 </option> 
  <option value='2411' > abc123post </option> 
  <option value='3301' > circuit id 50 </option> 
  <option value='2105' > fadhil </option> 
  <option value='2104' > faisal </option> 
  <option value='3002' > IPEN - SITE TEST </option> 
  <option value='3601' > Manual Circuit ID </option> 
  <option value='3302' > new circuit id fadhil </option> 
  <option value='1809' > try iframe </option> 
</select>
```

Comment: i cannot used <script src> because i do not have an access to the html file..i only have access to javascript and css file..

Comment: You can use JavaScript to include another JS.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I understand that you cannot change the select to anything else but those who are searching for similar thing and can change the `select` to `datalist`, it is very simple:

```html
<input list="weekday">
<datalist id="weekday">
  <option value="Sunday">
  <option value="Monday">
  <option value="Tuesday">
  <option value="Wednesday">
  <option value="Thursday">
  <option value="Friday">
  <option value="Saturday">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Oh man, I couldn't believe it can be that simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

I tried both `select2` and `selectize` and neither worked properly for me. I'm currently using jQuery 1.9.x. `Chosen` worked first try on 3.6 with basic tests but not sure if it will work well in current jQuery versions with all browsers.

[Update] In my production environments, I'm using jQuery 1.9.x with Chosen and it runs rock solid for my usecases.

Comment: Nice option, but according to their GitHub - it is deprecated.

Comment: Yes. I've been using it and its still solid. If there are no alternatives, its probably safe to use with older jquery. If you are latest and greatest jquery though, all bets are off ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to include other scripts like explained here:

[How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

```
function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
    var js = document.createElement("script");

    js.type = "text/javascript";
    js.src = jsFilePath;

    document.body.appendChild(js);
}
```

Then you could solve your problem using [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/):

```
includeJs("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js");
includeJs("https://cdn.rawgit.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/master/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js");

$(function() {
    $('select').selectize();
});
```

You will also need to include in your css the rules from selectize.css (or you could create a link element using a similar `includeCss` function in Javascript)

https://jsfiddle.net/qpyhjydp/

Note that in the fiddle I fixed the autoclosing `<select />` (not allowed)

Comment: Add some details? Why it doesn't work? What errors are you getting? You won't get much help on this site if you don't show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Display: none will not work foe IE11

I had same issue for search in select option.

What I did is disabled the un matched options and the hide them.

After this I have sorted the options to show only enabled options on top.

The code I have written is pasted below - please try to understand the logic I hope it will work

to disable the options use:

```
$("#addselect option")attr('disabled', 'disabled').hide
```

and to again enable it use:

```
$("#addselect option").removeAttr('disabled').show();
```

to sort by disabled options:

```
$("#addselect option").each(function (i, val) {
    if ($(this)[i].disabled) {
        moveDown("selectId");
    }
    else {
        moveUp("selectId");
    }
}

function moveUp(selectId) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
    var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = 1; i < selectOptions.length; i++) {
        var opt = selectOptions[i];
        if (!opt.disabled) {
            selectList.removeChild(opt);
            selectList.insertBefore(opt, selectOptions[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}

function moveDown(selectId) {
    var selectList = document.getElementById(selectId);
    var selectOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName('option');
    for (var i = selectOptions.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        var opt = selectOptions[i];
        if (opt.disabled) {
            var nextOpt = selectOptions[i + 1];
            opt = selectList.removeChild(opt);
            nextOpt = selectList.replaceChild(opt, nextOpt);
            selectList.insertBefore(nextOpt, opt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full option searchable select box

That also supports Control buttons keyboards such as `ArrowDown` `ArrowUp` and `Enter` keys

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590636/6569224

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using bootstrap in their project, a searchable select can be made using dropdown buttons.
Add an input field inside the dropdown menu and use javascript to filter through the options.

A detailed explanation with example can be found on the following blog:

https://medium.com/@akshat_yadav/searchable-select-in-bootstrap-16353b93c96d

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31697708)