# Keep dropdown <select> control open while filtering options

Tags: css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, mobile-website

I'm trying to implement this "filtered dropdown" pattern for mobile users:

[image]

By default, of course, a `<select>` control is closed, until the user clicks it open.

Is there a simple way to keep it always open? I understand it wouldn't strictly be a "dropdown" then - more like a traditional Windows "list" control.

(Multiple select is not appropriate for this application).

I'm using VueJS if that's relevant.

My current code:

```
    <p>Start typing your suburb name...</p>
    <input type="text" length="50" v-model="suburbFilter">
    <br>
    <select id="suburb-select" v-model="suburb" >
        <option v-for="suburb in filteredSuburbs">
            {{ suburb }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: show your code plaese

Comment: Sure. Not sure it adds much but ok :)

Comment: you can use ideas form here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796221/creating-a-select-box-with-a-search-option

Comment: Thanks, but those are jQuery components and I'm not using jQuery.

Comment: autocomplete using js:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Comment: autocomplete using vue.js:https://www.google.co.il/search?q=autocomplete+using+vue.js&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3tPGl08jcAhXFGuwKHVqxCuMQBQgiKAA&biw=1680&bih=917

Answer (score 1):

i use this component
https://paliari.github.io/v-autocomplete/, it's pretty customizable

Answer (score 0):

If it's always open, then you could use `<input type="radio">`.

Create a filterable list a la: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Then, instead of the `<a>` tags they're using, you can style a radio input in place of it.